# OpenCV - can't get VideoCapture to work

Tags: python, opencv

I have the following Python code that loads a video file and displays it in a window:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('file.mp4')
cap.open('file.mp4')
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("My Video Window", frame)

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

However, when i run it i get the following error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in imshow, file /tmp/opencv3-20160626-61731-v18vfg/opencv-3.1.0/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 281
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 66, in <module>
    cv2.imshow("My Video Window", frame)
cv2.error: /tmp/opencv3-20160626-61731-v18vfg/opencv-3.1.0/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:281: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function imshow
```

What could be the problem?
Thanks!

If i add:

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

I get:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in ipp_cvtColor, file /tmp/opencv3-20160626-61731-v18vfg/opencv-3.1.0/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 7456
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 66, in <module>
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: /tmp/opencv3-20160626-61731-v18vfg/opencv-3.1.0/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:7456: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function ipp_cvtColor
```

Comment: It looks like the frame step failed on `cv2.imshow()` so the frame needs to be initialized `out.write(frame)` http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d43/tutorial_py_video_display.html#gsc.tab=0

Comment: I edited my post with the error that i get after adding that line

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38542599/getting-opencv-error-assertion-failed is what you are looking for I believe

Comment: I don't think so.. it's a video that i downloaded from youtube, and the same code works for the same file if i try opening it using C++ in XCode.

Comment: Trying to open a different video doesn't give that error but for some reason i can't see it.

Comment: `cap.read()` is probably failing, you should make sure `ret` is not false. If `ret` is false OpenCV does not have the correct codec to read the mp4 file

Comment: How can i check it?

Comment: You need to check the value of `ret` and use it to decide whether or not to call `imshow` etc.  You can just use `print ret` to see the value

Comment: hmm well i think it fails before.. when i write `print cap.isOpened()` i get `False`. If i remove the `cap.open` part, it just tells me `WARNING: Couldn't read movie file`

Comment: that's for the same reason: either codec not supported or file not found.